# What makes an object reflect the colour that we see?

Tags: optics

If a rubber ball is red, I know that it is absorbing all colours except for red, which it is reflecting. So there is not actually a part of the object that contains any red. But what tells an object to reflect the light that it does? Is it something in the surface that does not let that wavelength enter it?

Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I know that it is atoms that do this, but what makes an atom reject some colours and allow others?

Comment: It's not atoms, it's molecules. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dye

Comment: This is a very common question.  If you put your title into a search engine you will find plenty of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure one of the processes is electrons going into orbitals with lower energy, releasing the energy difference as light. Quantum mechanics describes rules for how this may happen. They probably ended up in an orbital of high energy by the system absorbing external light.